# Android Service member variable goes null after running for some time

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to create a foreground service to communicate with a bluetooth device and I've done so using this structure:

Using a service, which also registers a BroadcastReceiver as a private member variable (to handle Gatt events), then the service is started using the startService command.  Then, I bind to that service inside my current Activity.  Inside the onStartCommand, I assign a BluetoothDevice object (my_device) which was passed as an extra in the onStartCommand intent to a member variable in the service.  However, after the service has run and the member variable is assigned, somehow it loses that member variable instance and it becomes null again when I try to do anything in the BroadcastReceiver that handles BLE Gatt Events.

```
public final class My_BLEService extends Service { 
  private My_BLEDevice my_device = null;

    private BroadcastReceiver gattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Problem: my_device is null inside this function
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Create the Foreground notification
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            // Get BluetoothDevice object
            if(this.my_device == null) {
                // Initialize the my_device object
                BluetoothDevice bleDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(My_AppManager.RFSTAR);
                this.my_device = new my_BLEDevice(bleDevice);
            }
            // Connect to the bluetooth device first thing:
            if(!this.isConnected) {
                this.connect();
            }

            // Start up the broadcast receiver here
            if(!this.receiverRegistered) {
                registerReceiver(this.gattUpdateReceiver, this.bleIntentFilter());
                this.receiverRegistered = true;
            }

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(My_BLEService.this, MonitoringActivity.class);
            // FIXME: Necessary? - notificationIntent.putExtra(My_AppManager.RFSTAR, bleDevice);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.logo_md);

            // TODO: Add close button
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("BLE Monitor")
                    .setTicker("BLE Monitor")
                    .setContentText("BLE")
                     // TODO; This isn't appearing correctly the first time
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_md)
                    //.setLargeIcon(
                    //        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    // Note: this doesn't seem to do anything (setting it to false doesn't change it either)
                    .setOngoing(true).build();

            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            if(this.receiverRegistered) {
                unregisterReceiver(this.gattUpdateReceiver);
                this.receiverRegistered = false;
            }
            if(this.isConnected) {
                this.disconnect();
            }
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not getting a new instance of `My_BLEService`?

Comment: No I don't know how service lifecycle works.  Does it trash and create new instances?

Comment: No idea - never written an android app (beyond toy examples). That's the only way I can see you ending up with `my_device` being null after it has been non-null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I created the problem myself.  The problem was, in my service I was resetting the member variable my_device in the onBind method:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    this.my_device = intent.getParcelableExtra(Kidpod_AppManager.RFSTAR);
    return this.kBinder;
}
```

with an extra which was not set when the bindService method was called in the activity, so it was setting it to null.